# Dialogflow training data

Tags: dialogflow-es

Training phrases are appearing as Events in Training tab of dialogflow. 
[image]

get me extra water bottles is training phare in one of my intents.

Comment: you may submit a bug!

Comment: This was a bug, which got resolved in a couple of days after reporting it.